# How can I convert this bash function to the fish shell

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I'm trying out the fish shell 2.0 to replace bash.  I'm trying to convert the following bash function to a fish function, but its giving me hell.   I have a several similar functions so if someone could point me in the right direction with an example I would be very grateful

```
connect() {
    if [ "$2" != "" ]
    then
            ssh -ti ~/.ssh/work/id_rsa user@host$1.domain.com "sudo ssh $2"
    fi
    if [ "$2" == "" ]
    then
            ssh -ti ~/.ssh/work/id_rsa user@host$1.domain.com "sudo -i"
    fi
}
```

Tried just replacing $1 and $2  with $argv[1]  and $argv[2]   but it complains about not being able to locate the end of block.   I know its because the scripting synxtax is quite different in fish.  I tried starting from a simpler function and had troubles with figuring out how to get it to do one thing if 1 variable is passed, and another thing if 2 variables are passed:

```
function testvarz
    switch "$argv[2]";
            case ""
                    echo "no second variable passed"
            case != ""
                    echo "second variable passed"
    end

end
```

but that doesn't work, if you pass 2 variable it does nothing, if you pass 1 it complains about

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a working function that's similar to your test function.

```
 function testvarz
      switch (count $argv)
          case 0
              echo 'zero'
          case 1
              echo "one $argv[1]"
          case 2
              echo "two $argv[1] $argv[2]"
          case '*'
              echo 'else'
      end
  end
```

You can use a similar structure for your `connect` function.

By the way, you should similarly use `$#` in your Bash function instead of trying to rely on `$2` being null. You can also use a `case` statement in Bash.

Comment: Note that there is no colon after the cases.